# Get JavaScripts asynchronously using getScripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get some scripts asynchronously on my login page:

```
        $.when(
                $.getScript("/Scripts/View/scroll-sneak.js"),
                $.getScript("/Scripts/kendo/kendo.custom.min.js"),
                $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
                    $(deferred.resolve);
                })
        ).done(function (res1, res2) {
            if (res1[1] == "success") {

            }
            if (res2[1] == "success") {

            }
            alert('all script loaded...');
        });
```

I have two queries here:

1. How can I leverage browser cache here, as getScript always take fresh script.
2. How can I have promise that this script will be available to all pages on same domain.

Alternate solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question is set cache true. Jquery [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) also mentions a way

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) {

  // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
  options = $.extend( options || {}, {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: url
  });

  // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
  // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
  return jQuery.ajax( options );
};

// Usage
$.cachedScript( "ajax/test.js" ).done(function( script, textStatus ) {
  console.log( textStatus );
});
```

For your second question: Please clarify more, what you want to achive?

Comment: what if script has size which can't be cached, then how i maintain it

Comment: If it's not cached then (Highly unlikely until nocache header is set) then it will be requested again. You need not to go that hard on leverage browser caching in this case.